# How to gather the value of a specific <span> from a variable containing the complete web page code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, web-scraping

I scraped a web page with the price of bitcoin and have the complete web page code stored in a variable. How do I extract the span:

```html
<span class="text-large2" data-currency-value>8128.61</span>
```

from the whole code? By the way the number 8128.61 changes every time the page is refreshed as the price is updated

Here is my full code:

```js
$.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/') + '&callback=?', function(data){
 console.log(data.contents);
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Web Scraper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
</body>
```

Comment: Put `data.contents` in a jQuery object then select from it as usual, eg `$(data.contents).find('span.text-large2').text()`. I suspect you'll need something more specific than that though as that will most likely match multiple elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory McCrossan! It works perfectly now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like below to extract the value

```
    $.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/') + '&callback=?', function(data){
    console.log($(data.contents).find('span[data-currency-value]').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this without Jquery also

```
var htmlData = `your html`;
var divNode = document.createElement("div");
divNode.innerHTML = html;
```

after this you can access all HTML element which is inside `htmlData`

like

```
divNode.getElementsByClassName("test")
```